# deleting a duplicate character in a string

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
function CreateHiddenWord() {
    var wordsTable = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
    var Hiddenletter = wordsTable[Math.floor((Math.random() * 26) + 1)];
    return Hiddenletter;
}
var WordToGuess += CreateHiddenWord();
```

How can I check if there are duplicate characters in `WordToGuess` and if there is, call `CreateHiddenWord` again.

Comment: You just draw one letter when calling `CreateHiddenWord` maybe you should call it: `GetRandomCharacter()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the confusing function name that actually returns a single letter, not a word:

```
do {
    var newChar = CreateHiddenWord();
} while (WordToGuess.indexOf(newChar) >= 0)
WordToGuess += newChar;
```

However, it is worth noting that this loop is not guaranteed to ever quit! If you are only creating small random strings, it's probably not a problem, but if you ever try and create a 27 character string, it obviously won't work! The longer your string gets, the harder it'll be to draw a random character that you haven't drawn before.

A better solution is to create an array of your candidate letters, draw a random letter, and then remove that letter from your array. That way you won't have to keep looping to try and find non-duplicates.

I'd look for something like this (assuming the variable `length` contains the desired length of your string):

```
function WordGenerator() {
    var letters = ['A','B','C',...];
    this.GetNextLetter = function() {
        if (letters.length) {
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random * letters.length);
            return letters.splice(index,1)[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you want a new word:

```
var myGenerator = new WordGenerator();
var word = "";
for (var i=0; i < length; i++) {
    word += myGenerator.GetNextLetter();
}
```

Comment: +1 For warning about the loop and suggesting an alternative. Shuffling the array and getting a subset would work too.

Comment: You will need to assign `GetNextLetter` to the context `this` so it becomes public

Comment: You also have to return the first element of the result of `.splice`. And maybe you want to return `null` when there are no letters left.

Comment: Thanks NULL and Felix, hopefully now fixed.

Comment: Now it's fixed ;) `.splice` always returns an array.

Comment: @FelixKling: Good point. Morning coffee's not quite kicked in yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`do...while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) loop until you get a unique character. Also using [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) will tell you about duplicates:

```
var WordToGuess = "MYWORD";
do {
    var char = GetRandomCharacter();
} while ( WordToGuess.indexOf(char) > -1 );   

WordToGuess += char;

function GetRandomCharacter() {
    var wordsTable = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
    var Hiddenletter = wordsTable[Math.floor((Math.random() * 26) + 1)];
    return Hiddenletter;
}
```

---

Actually one of the places `do...while` goes better than a regular `while`.

Answer (score 0):

`/(.)\1/` will match a double character.

Sorry I should explain that a bit better!

This is a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) used as follows...

```
if (/(.)\1/.test( WordToGuess )) CreateHiddenWord();
```

`/` delimits the regular expression itself

`(.)` matches any character and records it as a captured group

`\1` matches whatever the first (in this case, the immediately preceeding) group was - ie a repetition.

`.test()` applies this expression to a string and evaluates to `true` for a match and `false` for no match.

Comment: Duplicate characters don't have to be consecutive. This expression would only match if the characters were consecutive. It fails for `ofo`.

Comment: @Sly: That matches any two characters, even `42`.

Comment: @Felix Thanks for saving me the trouble ;)

Comment: @FelixKling LOL. I can tell I'm not awake yet. Read it wrong.

Comment: @FelixKling I've only just realised that the OP never actually stated that they wanted to match consecutive duplicates/double characters. I just read it like that! Oh well. I wondered why I hadn't got any upvotes for my awesome answer!